# Git repo not recognising files after I deleted and re-added them one folder higher

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal, version-control

I had an unnecessary empty parent folder in my git hierarchy, so I cut and paste the entire folder structure from my git repository, removed the old folder, and pasted the contents i wanted one level higher, and committed and pushed again. Now git does not recognise that any files exist in the new folder. I have confirmed this is not an issue with my .gitignore or git/info/exclude. I have tried running `git add .` to no avail.

So previously it was

Root folder => oldFolder => myFolder

I changed it to remove oldFolder so it is now

RootFolder => myFolder

But now git just shows the name of myFolder in rootFolder but believes it is empty, even though it has many sub folders and files.

Is there a terminal command i can run to get git to re-recognise the contents of myFolder?

I am running macOS Mojave on a macbook pro if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't lose your .git folder?

Comment: try running command - `git update-index --really-refresh`

Comment: Was the “one level higher” still in the repo?

Comment: @aydinugur how can I check this? Where should it be?

Comment: @Arpit this didn't work but thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox no

Comment: It’s not in the repo anymore? Git would see that as a removal.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes but the previously sublevel folder (myFolder in my example) is in the filesystem just under the root folder, but its contents are not being recognised by git

Comment: Look for a “.git” folder in the folder you thought the repo was in. It might be hidden, so make sure hidden files and folders are visible.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I still have the .git folder

Answer (score 2):

I had a duplicate .git folder existing inside the original subfolder myFolder, therefore git thought it was another entire repository and ignored it. Deleting that rogue .git folder and running `git add .` again made it see the files.